# What architecture to use for AJAX calls?

Tags: architecture, ajax

I am working on a website with PHP as backend.
There are things from the front-end which I'd like to accomplish using AJAX calls.

Which of these methods should I use to design them and why?

- Call to different PHP files for different uses
  [image]
- Call to the same PHP file, with instructions on what to do
  [image]
- A RESTful API
- Any other better way?

Comment: In general, how much functionality do the different actions share?

Comment: @Izkata: Apart from the very common ones (Session Validation, Database Connection, etc.), let's say that the different actions do **not share much in common**.

Comment: You could also have AJAX.php accept all the requests, and `require('like.php')` or comment.php to handle the specifics. Thus AJAX.php has one purpose: handle request, but you only need to handle requests in the one file.

Comment: @zeel: that's the second architecture in my question, right?

Comment: @Fa773NM0nK Oh I guess so, the illustration makes it look like AJAX.php dose all the work.

Comment: one would usually put the whole api into one file (possibly using classes from elsewhere) to offer a REST-api. But it wouldn't be externally visible how that API is implemented – your frontend makes requests like `POST /api/item/12345/like` or `POST /api/item/12345/comment`.

Comment: @amon: Won't going the RESTful route for PHP have to involve the htaccess file? Won't that bring web-server dependence to the project?

Comment: Good question, although platform specific configuration isn't as bad as platform-specific code. However, you already have such a config dependency by using CGI to run your scripts, I assume (or are you using something else?). It isn't much harder to route all requests through a single (preferably persistent) program that then dispatches the request to the API. This is at least how most modern web frameworks work, without locking themselves into one server. However, I have little experience with PHP, and wouldn't be able to recommend a technology stack for that.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at building a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_Web_Services). you can have clean urls that represent resources and these can be mapped to php servers in variouse different ways.

```
POST  /like
    { 
      userId: 'foo',
      itemId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }

POST  /comment
    { 
      commentText: 'bar',
      itemId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
```

The [Slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) provides a quick and easy way to set up a REST api in php

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally setup Slim on my system. (Had real trouble with apache's rewrite module and the .htaccess file). However, this solution is platform-configuration specific. If I want to move to a different web-server, I need to find a way to redirect all calls to index.php (all arguments intact). Is REST the only way to go?

Comment: good job setting up slim, in php the .htaccess file is what you'll need to use. REST is language agnostic based on HTTP so moving to another backend tech stack should be doable.